# Membership duration in profile is longer than the site's private beta length

Tags: support, bug, area-51, private-beta

I'm participating in the private beta phase of the [Pets Stack Exchange proposal](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/44686/pets). On the proposal page it shows that the site has spent 3 days in private beta.

But according to my profile on that site, I have been a member for 5 days.

[image: profile error]

What is the reason for this dispute in statistics?

Comment: They may have configured the accounts before actually sending out the private beta link.

Comment: I think it'd be better tagged as [tag:bug] instead of [tag:discussion].

Comment: @Emrakul I signed up 4 days ago when I got the beta link

Comment: @Emrakul note that it also states that the OP has visited for 5 days.

Comment: I had this exact same thing happen, I just live with it (but are curious as to why it happens though).

Comment: By the way, your screen shot is revealing information that wouldn't be available to other people viewing your profile (email address and real name).

Comment: @MonicaCellio Pls how does that affect the question?

Comment: It doesn't; I'm just pointing it out in case you didn't want to leak that private information to the whole Internet.  (I accidentally leaked my IP address in a screen shot once and was glad to have it pointed out.)  If you don't care, no big deal!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The number of days shown on your profile is correct; Area 51 is under-reporting.

All Stack Exchange times are in UTC.  We received the email on what would have been late Tuesday UTC.  Assuming you created your account promptly (looks like you and I both did), you got credit for those couple hours of Tuesday.  Now it is Sunday (UTC), so six days inclusive (which your profile now shows).

However, Area 51 is (now) showing 4 days.  Maybe Area 51 didn't count Tuesday and/or isn't on UTC, but that would only explain being off by one day.  So it sounds like Area 51 is being overly conservative, for some reason unknown to me.

Comment: I guess so. I signed up immediately i got the mail